# Bringing text down into the center with css

Tags: html, css, padding

Hello I am needing some help with my website. As you can tell from the image I have provided I need the text to be centered in the middle of the rectangular box. How do I go about doing this?

[image]

My css is,

```
.extendcontainer {
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.1); // Transparent White Background
    background: #fff; // Left as a fallback for older browsers
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this rule

```
padding-top:40%;
```

Like this

```
.extendcontainer {
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.1); // transparent white
    background: #fff; // Left as a fallback for older browsers
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding-top:40%;
}
```

You can play with `%` to adjust it.

Answer (score 3):

set the height of the box and the line-height of the box to be the same.

Example:

```
.extendcontainer {
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.1); // transparent white
    background: #fff; // Left as a fallback for older browsers
    color: #FFFFFF;
    height:30px;
    line-height:30px;
}
```

Doesn't work for multiple lines though

Answer (score 0):

You can using `vertical-align: middle;`

```
.extendcontainer {
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.1); // transparent white
    background: #fff; // Left as a fallback for older browsers
    color: #FFFFFF;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using line height is probably the easiest, if the text will always be on one line.

Looks like your container is 38 pixels high. To exactly center your text, try adding this:

```
.extendcontainer {

  line-height:38px;
  height:38px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

using padding-top may show the content centered for the screen that you are viewing currently. If the same page is seen from larger sized monitors, it may not. It is highly appreciated to use

```
vertical-align: middle;
```

so that, it is centered in all size monitors.